# Two different keys decrypting same content in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, cryptojs

Is it possible (for example, using some library) to encrypt a secret using two keys in such a way that each of these keys (separately) is able to decrypt this secret.

Comment: You could make them look superficially different, but ultimately each key would need to be processed in such a way that you end up with the same decryption key. Perhaps you can more fully describe your scenario. Why is it useful to have two different keys?

Comment: Thanks for answer, I need two decryption keys for security reasons. For example, one key would be used "on a daily basis" and the other would serve as a backup, stored on a separate flash drive

Comment: But how is that in any way an improvement over using the same key? The only advantage I can think of to having two independent decryption keys is that if one is ever leaked, you can tell which one was leaked. But that does not protect your data in any way.

Comment: I know it doesn't add another security leayer. In my scenario second key will be used by another user. So user1 adds 2 keys A and B and key B is sent directly to user2 so now user1 uses key A do decrypt smth and user2 uses key B. I just wonder if it's possible using some sort of library. Samir secret sharing is a way it can be implemented by it's not perfect.

Comment: If it adds no security, what is the point of having different keys? You have not articulated any reason that this would be worth implementing

Comment: You know what, actually you are right :) thanks!